# PHP Sessions work on localhost, but not on webserver

Tags: session, zend-framework2, localhost

I'm using Zend Framework 2's Session Container in my Controller.php to create sessions and transfer data from one action to another.

I'm doing some AJAX calls from jQuery to an action, which change the session variables on the server.

It works fine on localhost, but when I try to run it on my webserver, it only works half...

I'm using zfcUser as an authentication system, which works fine, with sessions. But my programm doesn't work properly.

I am using a hosting service and don't have access to php.ini and all that.

Any ideas? Do I need to post code?

Comment: UpperLowerCases probably, usually the root of all evil when it works on local windows but not on server linux ;)

Comment: @Sam, Could you explain that further? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Some classname being missspelled on a call or some variable being missspelled, something like that

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to search closely then I guess, but I believe I've got everything right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this does not work on ZF2's Session Container class:

```
$container->mystage++;
```

Had to change it to this:

```
$container->mystage = $container->mystage + 1;
```

Now it works. Is this zf2's fault or is this normal in OOPHP?

Really weird that it does work on localhost but not on shared server.